# In what scenarios can i use an auto-suggest textbox?

Tags: user-interface, autosuggest

I have a list of brand names for a particular product in the db. I can either display it on the screen using a drop down or and auto-suggest textbox.

I love the user experience of the auto-suggest textbox. But, is it right to use it here?

I would also want to know the best scenario to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on the number of items you need to display. If there are only a few, it gives hardly any advantage. But when there are many items, you can use it to filter out a lot of items, until there are only a few left. This makes finding the right item easier.

Comment: This make a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: But, how do you keep track of the Id. I know a few options, but what would be the prefer method of an auto-suggest textbox.

Comment: I would start a new topic for that... that is a whole nother question.

Answer (score 1):

The Auto-Suggest textbox should be used when the user will be entering in a new piece of data MOST of the time... and the dropdown box should be used when the user will be entering repeated data MOST of the time.

Comment: Well, if it's new data, auto-suggest is not going to help.

Comment: True... but the dropdown makes the user feel as though he NEEDS to pick from the list rather than typing in a new piece of info.

Comment: That said, I think I like your answer better... so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you offer both? One of the products I worked on had a drop down list of brand names but allowed the user to type free text as well. The drop down list would narrow as you typed characters.

**EDIT:**

This was using Java: `JComboBox.setEditable(true)` with some additional fiddling if I remember right.

Comment: well, he didn't really specify a language, but I agree, both could be used at the same time.  ComboBoxes in .NET have an auto complete collection just like a text box does.  So you could have an auto completing drop down box... but depending on the record size, this could get cumbersome to fill.